# Spring-pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The planar spring-pendulum is modeled by the set of equations
$$m\ddot{r}=mr\dotθ^2 + mg\cos\theta − k(r − L)$$
and,
$$r^2\ddot{\theta}= −2r\dot r\dotθ − gr\sin\theta$$
First we should define the *angular momentum* by $p_\theta = mr^2\dot\theta$ and the radial momentum by $p_r = m\dot r$ and rewrite the spring-pendulum system as a set of four first-order ODEs for $x = (r, \theta , p_r, p_\theta )$.
So I did like this, but I don't know if it's correct: 
$$\dot r = p_r/m, ~\dot\theta=p_\theta/mr^2$$
and,
$$\dot p_r = mr\dot\theta^2 + mg\cos\theta - k(r-L)$$
and,
$$\dot p_\theta = m(-2r\dot r\dot\theta - gr\sin\theta)$$
Now I have to find the equilibrium solution(s), $x_{eq}$ , of the equations, i.e., those solutions for which $x$ is constant.

How do I find these solutions?

Comment: Check my edit please

Answer (score 1):

By the product rule,
$$
\dot p_θ=\frac{d}{dt}(mr^2\dotθ)=2mr\dot r\dotθ+mr^2\ddotθ=-mgr\sinθ
$$
With your definitions you should also eliminate all of $\dot r, \dotθ$ for $p_r, p_θ$ from the final form of the equations.

Comment: When I eliminate θ˙ from p˙_r, I get an expression with p_θ:  p˙_r = p_θ^2/mr^3 + mgcosθ - k(r-L). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. For the equilibrium solutions it would also be sufficient to set $\dot r=\ddot r=\dotθ=\ddotθ=0$ in the original equations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we should have  $\dot{p}=-mgr\sin\theta$ and then, put all the first order ODE to $0$, and then the equilibrium result should be
$$
r=\frac{mg}{K}+L;
$$
$$ \theta=n\pi;$$ and finally
$$ p_r=p_\theta=0$$